# Limit poins of asequence

Tags: real-analysis

I know that we can construct a sequence with infinite but countable limit point .
example {1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,...}.
Can we construct a sequence with uncountable limit points.

Comment: A sequence is countable **by definition** AFAIK.

Comment: Yes.  For example, an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$ will have all of $\Bbb R$ as its set of limit points.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That sounds like a *Set*, not a *Sequence*.

Comment: @barakmanos it's a sequence.  Take
$$
a_1 = 1, \quad
a_2 = 1/2, \quad
a_3 = 2, \quad
a_4 = 1/3, \quad
a_5 = 2/3, \quad \dots
$$

Comment: @barakmanos it is unusual to refer to the limit points of a sequence, they are more commonly referred to as cluster points.  That being said, the question makes sense as it has been asked.

Comment: Another example would be, say, $(\sin n\sqrt{2})_{n\geq 1}$ which is dense in $[-1,1]$